# Adding row dynamically in android studio java

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add a new row by clicking the button `id-AddButton`, I found many google sources but I could not do so.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
                android:layout_width="93dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PersonName"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile Number"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PersonPhone"
                android:layout_width="325dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:hint="Mobile number"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PersonAddress"
                android:layout_width="328dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Delivery Address"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20sp"
                android:text="                         Order Details"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TableLayout

                android:id="@+id/MainTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" Date "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Item"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Quantity"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/AddButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/DoneButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Done" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need to add multiple rows dynamically when the button add is clicked, I am using Button.setOnClickListener in java but I am stuck on creating a new row. Please help me out if anyone can. One more thing, I had another account on which it is showing I have reached the limit of posting questions, can I know the limit and why it is showing so as I have only posted around 4-5 questions.

Comment: The space in "                  Order Details" is purposely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your onClickListner of the add button, implement the code to add TableRow and its element programmatically.

**JAVA PART**

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainTable);
```

**Create table row header for new row**

```
TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
tr_head.setId(10);
tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);    
tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**Add data to the row**
I'll add two TextViews to the TableRow created, you can add as much as you need.

```
TextView label_hello = new TextView(this);
label_hello.setId(20); // define id that must be unique
label_hello.setText("HELLO"); // set the text  
label_hello.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);      
label_hello.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); 


TextView label_android = new TextView(this); 
label_android.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
label_android.setText("ANDROID..!!"); // set the textlabel_android.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color 
label_android.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)

tr_head.addView(label_hello);// add the column to the table row 
tr_head.addView(label_android);
```

**After adding the columns to the table row its time to add the table row the main table layout that we fetched at the start**

```
tableLayout.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,                 
                     LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT));
```

**SUGGESTION**
It is recommended to use RecyclerView with a custom layout in this kind of scenario. The approach which you are implementing will cause serious performance issues if there's a number of data. Also, the way you can add/read/remove data can be made much easier using RecyclerView

Comment: is the background colour necsessary in tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); ?

Comment: Can you please explain the recycler view also?

Comment: SetBackgroundColor is not manadatory, please go through the article to get an idea of RecyclerView http://programmingroot.com/android-recyclerview-crudinsertupdatedeleteview-list-tutorial-with-example/